# Atualização de quantidade em uma tabela com sql server e c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

tenho uma datagridview que é preenchida assim que escolho os itens que no caso são produtos que contém quantidade na inserção do produto eu escolho uma quantidade e adiciono o item a datagridview, após finalizar a compra não estou conseguindo da baixa nessa quantidade. Criei um update mas atualiza apenas o ultimo produto adicionado a datagridview.
estou usando o código abaixo para atualiza a quantidade do produto.

```
  public void baixaEstoque()
        {

            //..
            string strCon = "Data Source = DESKTOP-MBLAUPI\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = db_controle_loja; Integrated Security = True";
            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(strCon);

            //..
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" update dbo.tb_produto set quantidade = quantidade - " + quantidadeTextBox.Text +
                                            " where id_produto = @id_produto", conexao);


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_produto", SqlDbType.Int).Value = codigoTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantidadeTextBox", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quantidadeTextBox.Text;


            try
            {
                conexao.Open();                                
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                //..

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {

                conexao.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Após inserir o item na venda você armazena seus itens onde? Em uma classe? Ou você apenas insere os dados no `gridview`?

Comment: insiro apenas no gridview.

Comment: Tenho que percorrer a gridview em cada item adicionado e alterar a quantidade no banco o meu código está funcionado apenas para um item no caso quando add dois itens ele alterar apenas a quantidade do ultimo da minha gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

É possível fazer operações diretamente no script *SQL*, porém sugiro que vc primeiro recupere a quantidade de itens no banco armazene em uma variável. Faça o cálculo depois grata isso no banco.
Ex:

```
// Consultando quantidade
int quantidadeItens = 0;

using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(CNN_STRING))
{
    string sql ="SELECT quantidade from tb_produto where id_produto = @id_produto";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_produto", SqlDbType.Int).Value = codigoTextBox.Text;
        quantidadeItens = CMD.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Atualizando a quantidade, com seu código alterando apenas `set quantidade = quantidade - " + quantidadeTextBox.Text`, para `set quantidade =  "  + quantidadeItens`

Comment: Seu exemplo não funcionou muito bem, o que necessito é percorrer a gridview em cada item adicionado e alterar a quantidade no banco o meu código está funcionado apenas para um item no caso quando add dois itens ele alterar apenas a quantidade do ultimo na minha gridview

Answer (score 0):

//..
                conexao.Open();

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in DataGridView_itens_vendas.Rows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" update dbo.tb_produto set quantidade = quantidade - " + quantidadeTextBox.Text +
                                    " where id_produto = @id_produto", conexao);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_produto", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dr.Cells[0].Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantidadeTextBox", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dr.Cells[2].Value;

                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
```

Fiz um for percorrendo a gridview e em cada linha eu peguei o valor de cada coluna e realizei o update na minha tabela no campo quantidade.